# I'm creating menubar

Tags: html, css, menuitem

I'm creating a menu bar using HTML and CSS, I want to put a centered border around the menu text

[image]

I'm using this code. Please tell me is this correct?

```css
.menu-text ul{
    list-style:none;
    color: #330000;
    margin: 18px -12px;
}
.menu-text ul li{
    display:inline;
    margin:19px;
    text-shadow:#cc6633 0px 1px 1px;
    font-size :17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;

}
.menu-text ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-text">
<ul>
   <li><a href="#"> Home</a> </li>

   <li><a href="#"> Operator</a></li>

   <li><a href="#"> Drive </a></li>

   <li><a href="#"> Booking </a></li>

   <li><a href="#"> Rider </a></li>

   <li><a href="#"> Logout </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does it work? If not what errors do you see? The quickest way to tell if something is correct in programming is to test it. This post as it stands is off topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: "Is this correct?" ?? Try it and you'll see

Comment: please see in image.. i want like that.. but when i add right border... i stays with text

Answer (score 0):

try this style

```
.menu-text ul li {
     display: inline;
     text-shadow: #cc6633 0px 1px 1px;
     font-size: 17px;
     font-weight: bold;
     border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
     border-right: 1px solid #513737;
     padding-right: 35px;
     background-color: rgb(193, 234, 142);
     padding-left: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-text ul{
 list-style: none;
 color: #330000; 
    background: #CCCC9A;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu-text ul li{
 display:inline-block; 
 text-shadow:#cc6633 0px 1px 1px;
 font-size :17px;
 font-weight:bold;
 border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
}
.menu-text ul li:first-child{
    border: none;
}
.menu-text ul li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #333333;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-text">
<ul>
   <li><a href="#"> Home</a> </li>
   
   <li><a href="#"> Operator</a></li>
   
   <li><a href="#"> Drive </a></li>
   
   <li><a href="#"> Booking </a></li>
   
   <li><a href="#"> Rider </a></li>
   
   <li><a href="#"> Logout </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you soo mcuh Dmitriy.. this is perfect as i want.. :) 
GOD BLESS YOU.